# File permission woes on an Ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo

I've set up an amazon ec2 instance and I'm have some file permission issues. I've created myself a new user and added myself to the following groups:

```
adm:x:4:me,ubuntu
sudo:x:27:me
www-data:x:33:me,www-data
ssh:x:108:me
admin:x:111:me
ubuntu:x:1000:www-data,me
me:x:1001:me
```

but when I `cd /var/www` I can't do simple commands without doing sudo. So I `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` to ensure that I'm in the owning group but I still have to type sudo for everything. If I `sudo su www-data` it works fine. Since I'm in the www-data group shouldn't I have the same privilages as www-data?

One strange thing I'm noticing is that when I `ls -l` it list the owner but not the group names. Could this possibly be part of the issue? Is is posible for a directory to not be part of a group?

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data 4.0K Oct 24 16:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     4.0K Oct 10 16:58 ..
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data 4.0K Oct 23 04:03 admin.mywebsite.com
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data 4.0K Oct  4 00:29 mywebsite.com
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data 4.0K Oct 23 04:03 staging.mywebsite.com
```

**Edit**
: It appears I had some alias messing with my `ls` command. By calling `\ls -l` I can see that all my files are in the correct group.

Comment: `chmod -R www-data:www-data /var/www` is not a valid command and would have given you an error message.  `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` is probably what you meant.

Comment: Could you add the output of `alias` as you to your question?  It sounds like you have the `-o` option to `ls`: `-o     like -l, but do not list group information`

Comment: @Ladadadada Thanks for the correction. I don't think I understand your question. Are you asking if I'm using the `-o` flag in an alias? I don't believe so unless it's in some bash file I'm not aware of. I only have the following aliases set for ls `alias ll='ls -lahG'
alias ls='ls -G'`

Comment: That is what I was guessing at.  You could try `\ls -l` to avoid all aliases.

Comment: Hey!! that worked. There must be some alias that I'm not aware of. I can't believe Amazon would put something like that on there. Still having the file permission issue though. If I do something like `git pull` it makes me do `sudo` first and then all my files are owned by root. How would I fix this?

Comment: Now that you can do an `ls -l` with the group column listed, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

sudo is slightly different to what you are trying to do. I recommend having a read about [rootsudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and [here to disable sudo](http://www.distrogeeks.com/disable-sudo-password-on-ubuntu/). This examples the sudo command and why it is good to use it.